# Gap above navigation bar?

Tags: html, css

Since adding a slide show into my site I now have a odd gap above my navigation bar. I am not sure on how to fix this. I tried what I did last time I had this happening but nothing ...

I have a JSfiddle set up: https://jsfiddle.net/7yj8rkbe/

HTML (for my nav bar):

```
    <img src="img/Logo.png" id="logo">
    <li>
        <a href="#">Other</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>


            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>

    <li>
        <a href="#">Store</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Official</a></li>


            <li><a href="#">Community</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Projects</a>

        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Official</a></li>

            <li><a href="#">Community</a></li>

            <li><a href="#">Open Source</a></li>
        </ul>

    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Forum</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Programming</a></li>

            <li><a href="#">Technology</a></li>

            <li><a href="#">Gaming</a></li>

        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a  id="nav-home" href="#">Home</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#information {
  top: 0;
}
```

You specified fixed positioning to that `div` but you forgot to set `top` value.